# Can i replace die() with Mage::throwException()

Tags: magento-1, coding-standards

I have to replace this code

```
die('Could not open socket');
```

because of **coding standard** can i replace with it **Mage::throwException()**

```
Mage::throwException('Could not open socket');
```

Comment: Why could you not? It's cleaner to catch an Exception than to `die` anyway. You could throw an `IOException` to be more precise.

Comment: @JulienLachal i have to replace **die** with some other function but don't want to effect the functionality.

Comment: Well, catching an Exception will also kill your process so the behaviour is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `die('Could not open socket');` with an **Exception** thrown by Magento:

```
Mage::throwException('Could not open socket');
```

Or you can have it thrown by PHP:

```
throw new Exception('Could not open socket');
```

Or even better, create your own **Exception**

```
class IOException extends Exception{}
```

And then use it instead of the standard **Exception** to better describe what kind of **Exception** you're throwing.